# Change Onelogin's OpenID configuration

Tags: openid-connect, openid, onelogin

Is it possible to change the OpenID configuration in `/.well-known/openid-configuration`? Namely, add more scopes to `scopes_supported` and add more keys to the JWKS endpoint.

Comment: You can add more scopes, not sure about JWKS endpoints.

Comment: @MayurDighe how can I do it in Onelogin?

Comment: check this out: https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/2/api-authorization/add-scope

Answer (score 0):

You must use API Authorization Management in order to configure OneLogin as an Authorization Server.

The OneLogin OIDC articles all point to the following:

```
https://developers.onelogin.com/blog/api-authorization-made-easy
https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/2/api-authorization/overview
https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/2/api-authorization/add-scope
```